# Change excel formula references when dragging across columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a row that I want to populate with formulas like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B93:B96,B46:B49)/SUM(B46:B49)
=SUMPRODUCT(C92:C95,C45:C48)/SUM(C45:C48)
=SUMPRODUCT(D91:D94,D44:D47)/SUM(D44:D47)
```

but dragging the formula only changes the alphabetical part of the index. Is there any way to have excel correctly change the array indices?

Comment: This does not provide a full answer, but it does maintain the appearance of the formulas.  Put your first formula in cell a20 of a new empty sheet.  Copy paste into B19, then into c18, then D17, etc.  Once you have done enough rows, cut-paste them back into b20, c20, d20, e20, etc, then cut paste A20:z20 to wherever you want it.  Obviously this is labor intensive, but less so than manually changing each array reference.  And it does leave you with formulas that look like the one you started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a cell with formula `=SUMPRODUCT(B93:B96,B46:B49)/SUM(B46:B49)` and you want to fill this right so that the cell in the next column but the same row has the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(C92:C95,C45:C48)/SUM(C45:C48)`. That is, you want the column to increase by 1 as normal, but also the row to decrease by 1.

You can achieve this using the `OFFSET` function. This allows you to construct a range that's a specified distance from a known range. We can use the `COLUMN` function to specify how much of an offset we want.

The ranges that we want are `B93:B96` and `B46:B49`, offset by -1 row and +1 column for each column past the first. Hence, `OFFSET(B93:B96, -1, 1)` will return a reference to `C92:C95`. However, our reference will naturally update the column, so we can leave the column offset out.

For the range that is `B93:B96` in the original formula, in the first cell we want `OFFSET(B93:B96, 0, 0)`, in the second we want `OFFSET(C93:C96, -1, 0)`, in the third we want `OFFSET(D93:D96, -2, 0)` and so on. We can use `=COLUMN(A1)` to get a result which is the number of the current column (because the reference will update to B1 in the second column, etc). Combining these, we can use
`OFFSET(B93:B96, 1 - COLUMN(A1), 0)`
which we can simplify by altering the reference:
`OFFSET(B94:B97, -COLUMN(A1), 0)`
In the first cell this translates to `OFFSET(B94:B97, -1, 0)` which is `B93:B96`. In the second cell the formula will fill right as `OFFSET(C94:C97, -COLUMN(B1), 0)` which is `C92:C95`.

So the two references we need are `OFFSET(B94:B97, -COLUMN(A1), 0)` and `OFFSET(B47:B50, -COLUMN(A1), 0)`. Hence the formula will be

`=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(B94:B97, -COLUMN(A1), 0), OFFSET(B47:B50, -COLUMN(A1), 0)) / SUM(OFFSET(B47:B50, -COLUMN(A1), 0))`

There is one final complication. When I was testing this on my copy of Excel 2007, I found that inside the `SUMPRODUCT` formula, `COLUMN(A1)` was returning an *array* containing the value 1, rather than just the value 1. (You can see this in the Evaluate Formula dialog box: when it evaluates `COLUMN(A1)` the result is `{1}` rather than just `1`, and the `SUMPRODUCT` expression gets two `#VALUE!` arguments and winds up being 0.) Depending on your version this may not happen to you. If it does, wrap the `COLUMN(A1)` inside a `SUM()`, like so:

`=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(B94:B97, -SUM(COLUMN(A1)), 0), OFFSET(B47:B50, -SUM(COLUMN(A1)), 0)) / SUM(OFFSET(B47:B50, -COLUMN(A1), 0))`

You'll note I haven't wrapped the final `COLUMN(A1)` in a `SUM()`; that's because this one returned a number as usual, not an array reference. I assume that since the `SUM` function does not accept array references, Excel realised that we didn't want an array out of `COLUMN` in this case.

Comment: very nice approach! Maybe with a couple of pictures it would be even more clear.

Comment: This seems to be moving the references the wrong way when I drag across the cells. I will play around with it a bit more and see if I'm doing something wrong.